# $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x\!yf(y)\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac{a}{2}$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous real-valued function on $[0,\infty)$
>   such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a$ for some $a\in\mathbf{R}$. Show
>   that $$
> \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x\!yf(y)\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac{a}{2}
> $$ where the integral is taken with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

This is from an old real analysis prelim. I have no idea where to start or what results might be applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have continuity, why not use L'Hopital? We are looking at

$$\frac{\int_0^xyf(y)\,dy}{x^2}.$$

The denominator $\to \infty,$ and both numerator and denominator are differentiable (the numerator by FTC), so we are entitled to look at

$$\frac{xf(x)}{2x} = \frac{f(x)}{2} \to \frac{a}{2}.$$

Thus $a/2$ is the desired limit.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x) = a$, there exists a positive number $M$ such that $|f(x) - a| < \epsilon$ for all $x \ge M$. Now since $$\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x yf(y)\, dy - \frac{a}{2} = \frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x yf(y)\, dy - \frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x ya\, dy = \frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x y(f(y) - a)\, dy,$$

then

\begin{align}\left|\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x yf(y)\, dy - \frac{a}{2}\right| &\le \frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^M |y(f(y) - a)|\, dy + \frac{1}{x^2} \int_M^x |y(f(y) - a)|\, dy \\
&< \frac{C(M)}{x^2} + \epsilon\frac{(x - M)^2}{2x^2},
\end{align}

where $C(M)$ is the constant $\int_0^M |y(f(y) - a|\, dy$. Taking the superior limit as $x\to \infty$ yields

$$\limsup_{x\to \infty} \left|\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x yf(y)\, dy - \frac{a}{2}\right| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, the result follows.